# Working with retrieved core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

Can't seem to find any Q&A or anything that helps me with this, but if you find some feel free to link! 
I've extracted data from a Core Data entity and using setPropertiesToFetch i have extracted a list of 'line numbers'.
 Now what i want is to take any line numbers that are set as nil and change them to 0.

Problem 1) 'unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x59ef30'. I know this error is from the 'if' line through commenting out others but i'm not sure what has caused it!

Problem 2) What i want it to do after increasing count is run again so it checks the next object but i'm really unsure as to the best code to do this with. Any suggestions of methods/code snippets/tutorials will be lovely!

Here is the code (The fetch request above works just fine :) )

```
changeTo0 = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"What is even in this array anyway? %@", changeTo0);
[fetchRequest release];

NSLog(@"In the array there is %u records", [changeTo0 count]);

NSInteger count = 0;
Fsode *details = [changeTo0 objectAtIndex:count];
NSLog(@"In details we have %@", details);        

if ([details lineNumber] == nil){
   [details setValue:0 forKey:@"lineNumber"];
   ++count
   NSLog(@"HERE");
}
```

Comment: Could you say something about your model? Are you using `NSManagedObject` subclasses?

Comment: An unrecognized selector message should also include the name of the class and the name of the selector.  Those might be useful to know.

Comment: Sorry guys! Yes i am using NSManagedObject, i'm still quite new to objective C (2 months or so) so bare with me lol. Hang on will get the error...

Comment: NSKnownKeysDictionary1 lineNumber]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x59ef30
2012-09-26 09:49:38.059 App[383:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSKnownKeysDictionary1 lineNumber]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x59ef30'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the first question, you should say something about the error (see Phillip Mills comment) and model. Does `Fsode` entity have a property called `lineNumber`? What type is it?

About the second question, execute only once the request like the following:

```
NSArray* results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSLog(@"What is even in this array anyway? %@", results);

int count = 1;
for(NSManagedObject* obj in results) {

    // I suppose lineNumber is of type NSNumber
    int numberValue = [[obj valueForKey:@"lineNumber"] intValue];    
    if(numberValue == 0) {

        [obj setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count] forKey:@"lineNumber"];
        count++;
    }
}    

[fetchRequest release];

// do a save here...
```

P.S. Reading your code, I'm not sure about the second question. Feel free to explain what you want to achieve.

The code I used increment the `lineNumber` for each object that has a line number of zero.
So the first object has 1, the second 2 and so on. If you want to put a constant line number for those objects replace

```
[obj setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count] forKey:@"lineNumber"];
```

with

`[obj setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"lineNumber"];` and remove the `count` (it's the same as your code does).

Comment: FSODE has lineNumber as int32 and YES a for loop, how silly of me not to think of that, let me try that hold on

Comment: And am i right in saying a save is done via 'if (![context save:&error]) {
         }
'

Comment: Ok, no error, but my save doesn't seem to work lmao >.< marked this as correct =D

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand if this a question or not. Anyway, yes, you could use `save` to save the context. Why doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, i'm a bit useless sometimes. The bit you've given me has solved both of my previous problems. But now my save is not working, but i can look into that :)

Comment: Ok, happy to see that helped. Cheers.